# Overlay bigger than video under it

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put a video under a purple layer but my video doesn't fit the overlay correctly.

[image]

Or if I delete this `background-size: cover;` in home section looks like this:

[image]

```css
.videoContainer {}

.videoContainer .overlay { /* ? */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: .5;
}

.videoContainer video {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

.home-section {
  // background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url('?');
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-section section">
  <div class="videoContainer">
    <video autoplay loop muted>
      <source src="?" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edited: added source code link:

[Download source code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o-9QfEUEt6kCO9ZYm_KdhmgARPy-31oG/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I'm wondering why your div ends between the video tags?

Comment: cause i'm iOS guys who is very focus on friday. Thanks for noticing but it doesnt resolve the problem.

Comment: checked like 10 times

Comment: except "div" not right place yes

Comment: as I said earlier it doesnt resolve the problem

Comment: `.overlay` should possibly have `position: absolute` not `position:fixed`. Here is a minimal fiddle showing how I would place an overlay inside an element so that it filled the element: https://jsfiddle.net/ozpjzkrn/

Comment: unfortunately :(

Comment: It is difficult to debug further without more information. You haven't shown us any of the styles that determine the height of `.home-section` or `.videoContainer`, for instance. We need HTML and CSS that will allow us to reproduce the bug you describe it in a browser. Regarding `position:fixed`, it removes an element from the document flow and positions it relative to the viewport, so it surprises me that this is what you want in this case. I would imagine that you want it positioned relative to `.videoContainer` instead?

Comment: added source code link feel free to check it

Comment: So `.overlay` was a complete red herring since it is commented out...

Comment: In future I suggest that you provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. That will make it much easier for answerers to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the source code you linked to, here are CSS changes that I think will do what you are trying to achieve.

The two issues I see with your current approach are that you are not stretching the video to fill `.home-section`, and neither are you stretching `.home-section`'s background image (the overlay) to fill `.home-section`.

```
.home-section {
    position: relative;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(../res/bg_color_home.png);
    /* make sure to remove the z-index declaration */
}
.videoContainer {
    /* make video container fill its parent: */
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* move it below .home-section: */
    z-index: -1;
}
.videoContainer video {
    /* make the video fill its parent: */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* and retain its aspect ratio: */
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Please note that the method of stretching the video to fill its container (`object-fit`) may not work in all browsers, and depending on the level of browser support you wish to provide, you may want to use a different method for scaling the video. I have used it because it is quick and easy.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.